# show result from json with axios

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, vue.js, axios

Hi i am try to show json file result with vue.js the target is that result will be showed on value.

this is my code:

```
    data () {
            axios.get('http://localhost:3000/statcard').then(response => {
            this.items = response.data;
            this.items.forEach(item => {
            this.statsCards.push({ type: 'warning', icon: 'ti-server', title: 'Cases', value: item, footerText: 'Updated now', footerIcon: 'ti-reload' } );
            })
          })  

          return {

            statsCards: [
              {
                type: 'warning',
                icon: 'ti-briefcase',
                title: 'Cases',
                value:  total_orders,
                Time1: '08:00',
                valuenow: '250',
                textValueNow: 'Now',
                footerText: 'Updated now',
                footerIcon: 'ti-reload'
              },
]
```

and this is the result of my json file :

```
{"total_orders":389,"total_cases":1188,"total_cases_08":[{"numbers":"389","type":"orders","cron":"2018-02-15 08:00:19"}],"total_orders_08":[{"numbers":"1191","type":"Cases","cron":"2018-02-15 08:00:18"}]}
```

am trying to  show the **total_orders":389** on value on stascards

thank you for your help

Comment: If that JSON is your response, the code errors out at the forEach() (trying an array method on a non-array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, doing this should work:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data() {
      statsCards: []
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3000/statcard").then(response => {
      this.statsCards.push({
        type: "warning",
        icon: "ti-server",
        title: "Cases",
        value: response.data.total_orders,
        footerText: "Updated now",
        footerIcon: "ti-reload"
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: only if you put it inside the promise.

Comment: Indeed, he would need to deal with the async request otherwise or use states.

Comment: @velour  i have error Module build failed: SyntaxError: this is a reserved word (181:8)  this.statsCards.push:

Comment: See updated answer, might be fine now (and very similar to your Vue instance code I suppose).

Comment: @velour Thanks you ... :-)